# DataTable.update -

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm pretty new to .NET so this might be basic stuff.

Here is my code:

```
        adapter1 = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT top 0 * FROM [aTable]", connection)
        cb = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter1)
        adapter1.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand 
        adapter1.Update(dataSet1, "[aTable]")
```

Basically, what I want to do is an Insert into this table. However, some of the values that I want to insert can already exist in the table aTable on other rows except for 1 column that differs. However I do NOT want to do an update any rows but INSERT a new row, always. But as of now I always get an UPDATE on old rows that has similar values.

How do I decide which column should be in there WHERE-clause in the .update()-function? Or is there any better method to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can specify the look of the update command, using [SqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Look at the example:

```
' Create the UpdateCommand.'
Dim command As SqlCommand command = New SqlCommand( _
    "UPDATE Customers SET CustomerID = @CustomerID, CompanyName = @CompanyName " & _
    "WHERE CustomerID = @oldCustomerID", connection)

' Add the parameters for the UpdateCommand.'
command.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID")
command.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40, "CompanyName")
Dim parameter As SqlParameter = command.Parameters.Add( _
    "@oldCustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID")
parameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original

adapter.UpdateCommand = command
```